# Already caught exception, still gives error

Tags: java, exception

i'm trying to set a look and feel of my GUI. I already caught the UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, but when i compile i get an error that says UnsupportedLookAndFeelException must be caught or declared to be thrown. The error is at this line:                 Ne r = new Ne();

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

   try{
      UIManager man = new UIManager();
      man.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel")  ;
   }
   catch(UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex){}
   catch(Exception ex){}

   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run()  {
         Ne r = new Ne();
         r.setVisible(true);
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: is `Ne` an object type made by you? If it is, does the constructor have a `@throws UnsupportedLookAndFellException` statement? What about the class?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest reading some more on the try catch statements:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

All in all, it seems that not all your code that can throw the exception is surrounded by the try.catch block

If you have an error with Ne r = new Ne()... move it into the try catch statement.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

   try{
      UIManager man = new UIManager();
      man.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel")  ;
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run()  {
            Ne r = new Ne();
            r.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }
   catch(UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex){}
   catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

If you use an IDE such as eclipse, it has some build in error fixing methods that will surround the code you need which is a good start to figuring out what needs to be set in a try catch block

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how your code would catch the UnsupportedLookAndFeelException thrown by new Ne(). Why not just put the try-catch at the right level? ie:

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        Ne r = new Ne();
        r.setVisible(true);

    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e)
    {
       // Put some code here to do the right thing.
    }
 }
```